# "Point not in interval [-180,180)" Error with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I've created geospatial index on my collection using the statement with PyMongo :

```
self.geo_collection.create_index([('location',pymongo.GEO2D)],\
         min=0,max=700,name='test_name')
```

but when I try to execute the following query :

```
{'_id': ObjectId('4fa739422d38036937000000'), 'location': {'$within': {'$polygon': [[165, 10], [165, 90], [290, 10], [290, 90]]}}}
```

I always get a

```
database error: point not in interval of [ -180, 180 )
```

Can anybody help me figure out what's going on? Thanks.

Comment: maximum value of lat and long is 180. No wonder it's throwing an error because you have the value of 290....

Comment: @Flukey: Are the `min` and `max` in `create_index` supposed to override that?

Comment: but why would you want to override that? If the value is above 180 then it isn't valid. If you want to override it then you shouldn't be using geospatial indexes.

Comment: wouldnt make sense to override just min/max... the calculations (like distance) that geospatial queries need have to know what type of coordinate system they are dealing with.

Comment: Can you do a .getIndexes() on your collection, to make sure that the min/max were overridden properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geospatial indexing works as advertised. To use $polygon you will have to have mongodb version  1.9 or greater. I ran the following script on mongodb 2.0.4 without any problems

```
import pymongo

db = pymongo.Connection().foo
db.foo.create_index([("loc","2d")], min=0, max=700, safe=True)
db.foo.insert({"loc":(180, 50)}, safe=True)
db.foo.insert({"loc":(240, 490)}, safe=True)
db.foo.insert({"loc":(240, 530)}, safe=True)
polygonA = [ [ 165, 10 ], [ 165, 90 ], [ 290, 10 ], [ 290, 90 ] ]
for doc in db.foo.find({"loc":{"$within":{'$polygon':polygonA}}}):
    print doc
```

with the following result

```
{u'loc': [180, 50], u'_id': ObjectId('4fa7b47c81dde04973000000')}
```